# Can AWS's free tier broadcast a Twitch Stream via NodeJS on CentOS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, stream, centos, twitch

**The simplified question:**

> Is streaming video possible with Amazon EC2? 
> And if it can, will it likely run over the Free Tier monthly usage limit (considering if it's streaming a few hours-per-day)

---

**The longer question:**

I'm trying to figure out if this concept is possible at all before I start signing-up for AWS / EC2.

If I can somehow run a headless browser in NodeJS on the EC2 CentOS instance (thinking of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Zombie](http://zombie.js.org/)) and stream it's content to [Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv), is the sheer amount of video data likely to go over the usage limit (ex: 2-3 hours a day)?

## The idea

Basically, the idea is to run some sort of HTML5 app that the Twitch viewers can interact with via a Twitch Chat Bot (also created in Node). They communicate with the bot to influence the outcome of what gets shown.

*True*, on one hand - streaming a browser window might sound a bit excessive and could just have the players play the HTML5 app in their own browser, use something like [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) to login directly on the HTML5 app site and handle all messaging there (avoiding Twitch altogether), which would reduce the load to simple socket communication instead of pushing out large amount video stream data.

That being said... Twitch has a large community! Why not embrace it?

By keeping gamers within the Twitch interface, it keeps the means of communication and stream viewing experience familiar to them.

That being said (again)... if there are ways to embed a Twitch chat within another domain (where the HTML5 app is hosted on), that may be another approach worth considering. Not sure if this exists though.

But above all - I would really like to know if video streaming in general should be a concern on a free tier EC2 instance.

Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking of looking into streaming from a webserver to twitch or other streaming systems. However I have not spent much time on it yet.. I am willing to test out the streaming from my own machine and we can calculate how much data is going to be transmitted. I have a fairly massive bandwidth for my home internet, and if we can figure out how the protocol runs, we may be able to calibrate the data throughput. (Sounds like an interesting project if you are interested in playing around with it)

Comment: @The Lazy Coder: that does sound interesting! Even just knowing some numbers like what framerate, resolution and bandwidth settings achieves a good balance between delivering a watchable stream VS facing an expensive Amazon EC2 bill at the end of a month - that would be appreciated! :) (I suppose there are more factors to consider than the processing of the video stream itself though)

Comment: For now I am on another portion of the current project, but if you want to cobble together something I am willing to host it and at that point we can determine all of the features and fine tune it. Come find me at twitch.tv/superlazycoder

Answer (score 1):

Running one t2.micro EC2 instance for the month should be free under the free tier.

You'll will want to watch out for the data transferred.

- Data transfer into your EC2 instance will be free.
- Data transfer out to the internet will be free for the first 1 GB each month.
- Data transfer out to the internet will cost you for all data above the first 1 GB each month.

The prices for data transfer out will depend on the region you're using. For example, in us-east-1 (Virginia) you'll start paying $0.09 / GB each month for data out.

Full data transfer pricing can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

So it really is going to depend on the amount of data streamed. If you're lucky, it could be free or very low.